# Reset style on leaflet polygon on click

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have a map made with leaflet.js with a geoJSON layer consisting of 70-some polygons. Each time the user clicks on a polygon, it is highlighted and a side panel is filled with data and opened:

```
function clickFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
        layer.setStyle({
        weight: 3,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });

    info.update(layer.feature.properties);
    $( "#mypanel" ).panel("open");
}
```

That works fine. But I need to change it so that each time a polygon is clicked, it simultaneously gets highlighted AND the previously clicked polygon returns to the original style, so only one polygon is ever "selected" at a time.

I've tried this, but it doesn't work (the panel is no longer updated or opened):

```
var lastClickedLayer;
function clickFeature(e) {
    geojson.resetStyle(lastClickedLayer);
    var layer = e.target;
        layer.setStyle({
        weight: 3,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });

    info.update(layer.feature.properties);
    $( "#mypanel" ).panel("open");
    layer = lastClickedLayer;
}
```

Any help very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assignment is wrong, it has to be

```
lastClickedLayer = layer;
```

You also should add an additionally check if `lastClickedLayer` has already been set:

```
if(lastClickedLayer){
   geojson.resetStyle(lastClickedLayer);
}
```

Comment: I've got this same problem too, the issue I am having is detecting when a user clicks into another polygon, or clicks off the polygon and then clicks another polygon. If you click another polygon when one is already selected the click fires before the popupclose

Comment: This is actually proving to be challenging to get right, also taking into consideration when a user clicks the same region twice...